# How to use a variable globally inside a angularjs(1x) controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a array inside a angularjs controller which gets updated every time i call a function in the web page. I have declared a variable `var myArray = []` inside the controller, but every time i call the function the value of array is empty, i need its scope to be global so that each time i call the function from the web page the array gets updated instead being initialized each time... so that when then second time i click on the button it adds another hi instead of what i think it initializes the array each time

Html Code :

```html
<button ng-click="addToArray('hi')">Add to Array</button>
```

AngularJs Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp");
app.controller("MyController", function($scope,$window) {
     var myArray = [];
     $scope.addToArray = function(input) {
         myArray.push(input);
     }
})
```

Each time i press on add to array button, the array becomes a new one and adds hi only one time

Comment: what you meant by globally? are you using multiple instances of your controller?

Comment: also, there is a syntax error, remove `()` from function name `$scope.addToArray = function(input){myArray.push(input);}`

Comment: if you really need to use global variable, you could add them as property of  `$rootscope`, but using global variable is never a good idea.

Comment: @ajaiJothi thanks,  have edited the question; by globally i mean when i click on the button i want 'hi' to added first time and when i again hit the button 'hi' should be added for the second time to my array, so by globally i mean when the second time the button is clicked i want to have 'hi' to be added twice

Comment: You don't need to have global variable for that. The component will keep track of it's variable. as long as you don't remove and re-add the component to your DOM, everything should be fine.

Comment: as @Nicolas said, if the dom associated with your controller is not recreated, your code should work... if you want to access `myArray` in your template, use `$scope.myArray`.. I created a fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/ajai/4pvbhqmy/

Comment: as @ajaiJothi mentioned yes i was removing the added value in another function, thanks for pointing that out.. sorry for all your troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine in this example:

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope,$window) {
     var myArray = [];
     $scope.addToArray = function(input) {
         myArray.push(input);
         console.log(myArray);
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="addToArray('hi')">Add to Array</button>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks so much @georgeawg it seems i am removing the added value in another place in the js, thank you so much for taking your time to answer!!!